# XML DOMDocument php - query

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I've got this problem. I have an xml file which contains this code:

```
<Products>
<Product>
    <ID_Product>1</ID_Product>
    <ID_ProductKind>green</ID_ProductKind>
    <ID_ProductStatus>apple</ID_ProductStatus>
    </Product>
    <Product>
    <ID_Product>2</ID_Product>
    <ID_ProductKind>yellow</ID_ProductKind>
    <ID_ProductStatus>banana</ID_ProductStatus>
    </Product>
 </Products>
```

Now I would like to select ID_ProductKind and ID_ProductStatus where ID_Product is equal to one(1). Anyway the result of my query should be:

green apple

It's so simple in mysql. How can I do this in DOMDocument?

Regards, 
David

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're looking for a basic XPath expression.

It's not particularly elegant, but you might try something like this:
"//ID_ProductKind[preceding-sibling::ID_Product='1']/text()".

You can use something similar for ID_ProductStatus.

I'm not quite sure about concatenating the values -- perhaps you can handle this in your php code.  I see that there's a string-join function in later versions of XPath.